# Create Dynamic function, then call it in the opener

Tags: javascript

In a popup window, I create a string dynamically which represents a function existing in the window.opener

e.g. `funcstring = 'getProductListings("user_id",true)';`

This is one of several possible functions that could be created dynamically, so I can't just hardcode it into the window.opener function call.

Then I want to call this in the opener something like as follows, but I'm not sure how to structure it.

```
window.opener.funcstring; // Pure pseudocode; I have no idea how to construct it.
alert('Success');
window.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this like so:

```
window[functionName](params)
```

where functionName === "getProductListings" and params == "user_id",true

You can generally do the above like so:

```
window.opener[functionName](params);
```

I hope that helps